# How to use core query with mysql joins in cakephp 3.0?

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp

I am getting stuck on this core query it gives **fatal error**
Here is my query:-

```
$userTransactions = 
$this->query('select transactions.*,restaurants.title from transactions 
JOIN restaurants ON transactions.place_id = restaurants.id 
where (transactions.user = "'.$username.'" 
and transactions.place_type = "Cafe & Restaurants") 
order by transactions.id desc')
->fetchAll('assoc');
```

Here i have used this query but this gives me fatal error.I am using Cakephp 3.0
Can anyone help me. Thanks in advance:)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This query runs on Cakephp 2.0 But in Cakephp3.0 you have to use Like this
You have to set the connection like this:

```
$conn = ConnectionManager::get('default');
```

After that you have to use the excute statement, but make sure that you use proper prepared statements, and ***do not*** insert (user)data into the query directly, as that is a possible SQL injection vulnerability:

```
$userTransactions = $conn
    ->execute(
        '
            select transactions.*,restaurants.title
            from transactions
            JOIN restaurants ON transactions.place_id = restaurants.id
            where (
                transactions.user = :username and
                transactions.place_type = "Cafe & Restaurants"
            )
            order by transactions.id desc
        ',
        ['username' => $username],
        ['username' => 'string']
    )
    ->fetchAll('assoc');
```

Hope It helps!

See also

**[Cookbook > Database Access & ORM > Database Basics > Running Select Statements](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/database-basics.html#running-select-statements)**

Comment: That's a possible SQL injection vulnerability! Please **_never ever_** include (user)data into queries directly, always use prepared statements / bindings! **https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/database-basics.html#running-select-statements**

Comment: @ndm i understand Your point but according to question i just reply that

Comment: You're not obligated to repeat other peoples mistakes... that code is bad practice, and you shouldn't post something like that, even if the OP was explicitly asking for it! People that read this may think it would be OK to build queries like that, and that's how these vulnerabilities spread. Please update your question with an example that is safe to use.